# How can I initialize a list filled with previous initialized lists?

Tags: dart

The current code:

```
class A {
  List<int> listOne = [];
  List<int> listTwo = [];

  List≤int> listOfLists = [
    ...listOne,
    ...listTwo
  ];
}
```

Results in the following error for each list with an spread operator (...):

error: The instance member 'listOne' can't be accessed in an initializer.
error: The instance member 'listTwo' can't be accessed in an initializer.

What I know:

listOne etc. can't be referenced in another initializer

So what I tried: https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#implicit_this_reference_in_initializer

```
class C {
  int x;

  C() : x = defaultX;

  static int get defaultX => 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to translate that to solve my problem.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: You are trying to fill a list with empty lists, logic?.... Not found

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα It may just be a part of a simplified example. Their question doesn't rely on the contents of those lists so it doesn't matter either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly make a constructor and do the assignment there.

```dart
class A {
  List<int> listOne = [];
  List<int> listTwo = [];

  List<int> listOfLists;

  A() {
    listOfLists = [...listOne, ...listTwo];
  }
}
```

---

If you're using null-safety then you should add the `late` keyword.

```
class A {
  List<int> listOne = [];
  List<int> listTwo = [];

  late List<int> listOfLists;

  A() {
    listOfLists = [...listOne, ...listTwo];
  }
}
```

Comment: now I get this error: 'listOfLists' isn't a field in the enclosing class.

Comment: @ArvedFriese Where is this error? I can't reproduce that error with the code that it's my answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't refreshed my page and had still seen an old version.

Comment: now it works like a charm. Thank you so much! Also the mention for null-safety was perfect!